# How can I have a custom login page in EWL?

Tags: c#, authentication, web-applications, forms-authentication, enterprise-web-library

I have a web application using Enterprise Web Library and I've found the need to have a custom log-in page. I see that EWL provides one for me, but I want to be able to have some custom elements on the page and control how the user is logged in. How can I achieve this in EWL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create your custom log-in page. Let's call it `MyLogIn.aspx`.

The next step is to designate `MyLogIn` as the log-in page for some/all of the pages and shortcut URLs in your app. To do that for pages, override `PageInfo.LogInPage` and/or `EntitySetupInfo.LogInPage` and return a `MyLogIn.Info` reference. This setting is inherited from parent pages and entity setups. If you want all pages in your app to use `MyLogIn`, you only need to override the `LogInPage` property at the root of your page tree.

To use `MyLogIn` for your shortcut URLs, use the `logInPageGetter` optional parameter in the `ShortcutUrlResolver` constructor. Pass a function that returns a `MyLogIn.Info` reference.

The final step is to implement `MyLogIn`. You can design the page however you want and collect whatever credentials you want, but there are a few things you need, which depend on whether you still want to use EWL's UserManagement subsystem. If you do, you need to call `UserManagementStatics.SetUpClientSideLogicForLogInPostBack` during LoadData and call either `UserManagementStatics.LogInUser` or `UserManagementStatics.LogInSpecifiedUser` from a `DataModification`. If you are *not* using UserManagement, you're responsible for authenticating the user in your own fashion as part of a `DataModification`, before redirecting the user into the app.